# Chrome/IE doesn't request any resource across non-https in Facebook application

Tags: facebook, ssl, https, facebook-apps

There is a problem with Facebook applications/page tabs and Chrome/Internet Explorer users that have checked "secure browsing" setting in their profile but not only.

Problem rises when facebook opens our app by https protocol. Let's assume that we have app and all our resourcess accessbile by https. When user visits our app, **everything working but not iframe/JS widgets, provided by external sites without SSL** like some counters, instant messaging widget etc.

What to do if the page where widget comes from doesn't let us to generate ssl-version code, and also just changing http to https doesn't work because of lack of certificates/ssl enabled etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what the "padlock"/SSL indicator in the browser indicates is that the **whole page is secure**. 
That means, no insecure content is included on the page without explicit warning by the browser that that is the case.

There may be browser specific workarounds (aka bugs), but relying on them for your page to work is not a good idea.

The best "workaround" is likely to just contact the people hosting the widgets and inform them about your problem, or if possible just plain hosting the widgets on your own secure site.

Comment: Any workaround ? This is huge problem if you are making Facebook app where that widget (TripAdvisor exactly) is essential and the only element on page tab and it's not working for lot of users.

Comment: I have no "generic" workaround so a bit complex but here's an **untested** version; the problem in the script (at least the widgets I looked at, there are several more) seems to be a reference to "jscache.com" which is served by Akamai and has no HTTPS version. The only thing it serves up is a javascript that references a Tripadvisor URL. The Tripadvisor URL exists in a secure version, so if you could serve the jscache.com generated script yourself and serve it with a https URL to Tripadvisor, that _should_ solve it.

Comment: After another cup of coffee I should add that this workaround of course assumes that TripAdvisor doesn't change their site around so your script breaks.

Answer (score 1):

TripAdvisor widget

The answer is : replace this script tag with TripAdvisor script

This :

```
<script src="http://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=sswidecollectreview&amp;uniq=612&amp;locationId=1480219&amp;lang=en_US&amp;border=true"></script>
```

To This tag from TripAdvisor Script

```
<script src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/WidgetEmbed-sswidecollectreview?uniq=831&locationId=308116&border=true&lang=en_US"></script>
```

and add [ S ] character to link for images [https] like this :

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.tripadvisor.com/"><img src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/branding/medium-logo-12097-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"/></a>
```

To This :

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.tripadvisor.com/"><img src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/branding/medium-logo-12097-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"/></a>
```

its work ...